# Anatta during meditation

Tags: theravada

When doer and knower disappears is that the state where anatta found? Have reached the state experience of a mirage in appeared on doing work. Which  samadhi has involved?And mind  restlessness appeared when closer look at the restlessness it will disappears with samadhi.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to look for anatta. That's completely misunderstanding what anatta means. Anatta is a characteristic. Meaning every experience is anatta.
Look at experience (any experience) arise. You don't make it arise. That happens according to conditions. That is what anatta means.
Feelings, memories, hearing, thinking .... everything arises according to conditions. Whether you like it or not. You can't stop experience from arising.
That is what anatta means.

Don't try to reach stages. Don't try to gain anything. Just observe objectively.

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing anatta meditation, you are focusing your mind on anatta, So gradually anatta'll improve in your mind, and there isn't certain time where you find it at-once..Othewrwise you'll feel the parikamma/uggaha/patibaga nimitta according to the type of meditation you are doing,when you improve samadhi and reach to a jhana state,and also you feel ten fetters are reduced in some amount